# Debian - port redirect

Tags: php, debian, netflow

I have device, that sends some RAW data (NetFlow v9). I can set only IP adress and PORT of "data collector". For Example **192.168.0.10:8080**.

Is it some simple solution at Debian to redirect this to specific php script on common webserver port (:80), for example **192.168.0.10/SaveFromDevice.php**? And how i can get sended data to $_GET["data"]?

Thank you

Comment: So basiclly you are asking how to reroute/redirect traffic from `192.168.0.10:8080` to `192.168.0.10:80`?  If so you can add a firewall rule believe Debian uses iptables as firewall.. see the manual https://wiki.debian.org/Firewalls-local-port-redirection

Comment: bassicaly, but i need to redirect to 192.168.0.10:80/SaveFromDevice.php , because on index.php, there is another (web) application...